# Whats wrong with my remote control?

Tags: technology, batteries

I have this remote control:

[image: Remote Control Unit]

Sometimes if I press a button the TV does not react - although there is nothing in between that could block the signal between the red light and the remote control:

[image: Television standby indicator]

If I take the batteries out and put them inside again, everything works again. However, the batteries are 100% full:

[image: Battery tester showing full charge]

What is the problem here?

Comment: The red light is just a power indicator. Look for the actual location of the sensor on the TV.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik how do I find the actual location of the sensor? I am pretty sure its there where the LED is, because thats where it seems to work best.

Comment: The users' manual.

Answer (score 1):

The symptom described (intermittent operation, better after reseating the batteries) is caused by poor connection, likely due to oxidized contact surface on either the battery cells or the contacts in the remote.

One thing that may help is to carefully and gently bent the remote contacts (or stretch the spring contacts) so they put a little more pressure on the battery -- but this may not be possible in many remotes.  Rubbing the flat contact in the remote and both ends of each cell with a pink pencil eraser is likely to improve things a bit, as well (don't scrape with a metal tool or use an abrasive of any kind, as you'll remove the protective plating on the remote's contact plate).  If there's any visible corrosion (from a prior set of failed cells) it must be removed.

If these measures don't solve the problem, it may make more sense to purchase a "universal remote" (typically under $20).  Do try to check before purchasing that the remote supports your brand and model of television, but if the TV is new enough to be a flat screen, digital set (as opposed to a CRT analog type), that's virtually certain (remote signals have become more standardized in the HD era).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the batteries are not well secured inside, so they occasionally get moved and don't make good contact. If that is the problem, and you don't want to adjust them each time, you could put something non-conductive and not-easily-flammable (like a small piece of plastic) on the top of the batteries, that is, between the batteries and the battey cover (or at the side of a battery, if it moves sideways) in order to keep them in place.

(I can't see any problem with doing this but PLEASE CORRECT ME IF IT IS NOT SAFE TO DO.)